# Reduce the weight of a Glyphicon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, glyphicons

Is there a way to reduce the "weight" of Glyphicons?

I am using the "[ok](https://glyphsearch.com/?query=ok&library=glyphicons)" Glyphicon `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>` which displays like this:

[image]

Is there any way to reduce the weight to produce a thinner tick without reducing the font size? Changing the `font-weight` to `lighter` has no effect whatsoever.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Using white stroke is a way to do it

```
-webkit-text-stroke: 2px white;
```

Comment: This is a non-standard feature (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-stroke) and has not appeared in any W3C specification (http://caniuse.com/#search=text-stroke), so your results may not work in all browsers.

Comment: @joeshmoe301Thanks, it does play well in the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Support appears to be getting better, just thought i'd update.  It worked for me anyways

Answer (score 1):

You could apply the `font-weight` property on `::before` pseudo element to alter the font-weight:

```css
.glyphicon {
  font-size: 60px;
}

.glyphicon-light::before {
  font-weight: 100;
}

.glyphicon-thick::before {
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search glyphicon-light"></span>

<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>

<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search glyphicon-thick"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Works on **Different** background-color.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "[.fas || .glyphicon]" ).each(function( index ) {
      var color = $(this).parent().css("background-color");
      $(this).css("-webkit-text-stroke","2px "+color)
    });
});
```

> **Notice :** choose one of `.fas`  or `.glyphicon` .

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to do this in pure CSS?

Comment: We can not process **html DOM**  with pure CSS .if we want to effect all elements to take `-webkit-text-stroke` with different `background-color` we have to use `jquery` @Derek Brown .

Answer (score 0):

You can also use opacity on the `glyphicon` if you do not want to apply this globally.

```
<span style="opacity:0.25;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
```