# Bootstrap Glyphicon, How to change weight?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I don't see any change with any of the values I can specify in the CSS property font-weight. Do you know how to solve?

Thanks in advance

```css
.glyphicon-custom {
  font-weight: lighter;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="form-group has-feedback"><input type="search" class="form-control"/><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback glyphicon-custom"></span></div>
```

Comment: Have you had a look at [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42686104/reduce-the-weight-of-a-glyphicon)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the `font-weight` to the `::before` pseudo element, because it is where the content is written.

In the snippet below, I've given font-weights 100 and 900 to the icons respectively.

```css
.glyphicon-custom::before {
  font-weight: 100;
}

.glyphicon-custom-2::before {
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="form-group has-feedback"><input type="search" class="form-control"/><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback glyphicon-custom"></span></div>


<div class="form-group has-feedback"><input type="search" class="form-control"/><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback glyphicon-custom-2"></span></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Nisarg for the solution. Just a question: is 100 the max lightness I can use with glyphicons coming from bootstrap? I tried to decrease more but it looks like this is the "maximum"..

Comment: @Micky Yes, the font libraries generally control which values they support. The numeric values supported by browsers are 100, 200, 300 ... 900. I am not quite sure which values bootstrap supports though.

Answer (score 1):

```
.someSvg path {
    stroke: white;
    stroke-width: 3px;
}
```

```js
    <div style="width: 100px; height:100px;">
      <svg viewBox="-10 -10 120 120" class="someSvg>
        <path d="M 50,0 L 60,10 L 20,50 L 60,90 L 50,100 L 0,50 Z" class="arrow" transform="translate(85,100) rotate(180)"></path>
      </svg>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).